# ElastAlert Not Matching Exact Substrings

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I am trying to match the substrings `notify=warning` OR `notify="warning"` in a log message payload using an ElastAlert rule and the results are less than desirable so far using the rule filter I have included below:

`filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "message:\"notify=warning\" OR message:\"notify=\"warning\"\""`

The substrings I am searching for are in the middle of the `message` field but the results of my filter do not match for the quoted "warning" and it will also pick up messages that just have words like "WARNING" in them.  Any assistance in fixing my match would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ".keyword" to match exactly.

e.g.

`query: "message.keyword:\"notify=warning\" OR message:\"notify=\"warning\"\""`